# Not getting JWT token (id_token) for grant_type 'client_credentials' in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using **IS_BASE_URL/oauth2/token** end point to get JWT token.
but it return only **access-token**. Is there any work around to get JWT token
for grant_type **client_credentials** and set configurable expire time of JWT_token base on client and secret key credential (service provider base)?.

Comment: What is the IS version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

In later IS versions (IS-5.4.0 onwards) we have a configuration in the file identity.xml file as below.

```
        <SupportedGrantType>
            <GrantTypeName>client_credentials</GrantTypeName>
            <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.ClientCredentialsGrantHandler</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
            <IsRefreshTokenAllowed>false</IsRefreshTokenAllowed>
            <IdTokenAllowed>false</IdTokenAllowed>
        </SupportedGrantType>
```

Here you have to mention IdTokenAllowed as true. Then you will get id token along with the access token for client_credential grant type.

At the moment we don't have a way to configure id token or JWT token expiry time per application instead only global configuration is there. You could set id token expiry time globally in identity.xml file inside the tag IDTokenExpiration (identity.xml file by default contains the tag IDTokenExpiration)

```
<IDTokenExpiration>3600</IDTokenExpiration>
```

**Update:-** From the latest identity server (IS-5.6.0) onwards you could configure id token expiry time per application. You could refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On for more information.

Comment: Thanks Nilasini for your continuous support, After done above changes now I am able to get id_token in response. Thanks again for your quick update.

Comment: On a separate note, it does not make sense to have id token for client credentials grant type, because the there is not user authentication in this grant type (just client is validated). That's the reason for not having the id token by default enabled for client credentials grant type. Just for backward compatibility we have a configuration to enable it.

Comment: Yes your concern is correct,But we authenticate consumer application using grant_type 'client_credential' instead of user authentication and expect JWT token in authorization header for future all subsequent service call.

Answer (score 0):

You need provide the scope as openid.

Sample curl request is as follows.

> curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid"
>         -H "Authorization: Basic ZjdJbk9mQ2dxRUZyckVna1hQa2dFU1BwUDk0YTpJZkhSZ0dsOHVzOXI4TlkybkxPN0tiQXQxQTRh"
>   TOKEN_ENDPOINT

Comment: yes, I set openid in scope value parameter still it's not working.